# Extracting Data From List of Tokens in Java

Tags: java, list, parsing, csv, token

I have a string array that I converted to a list which I iterate through via my while-loop in the code snippet below to parse a .CSV file. There are 15 elements per line of the .CSV file being parsed and I would like to access each element individually so that I can pass that data to another function. How do I extract each of these items one by one from the list of tokens?

```
 try {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filePath), ',');

    // Reads the complete file into list of tokens.                  
    List<String[]> rowsAsTokens = null;

    try {
        rowsAsTokens = reader.readAll();
        } 
        catch (IOException e1) 
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }

    Iterator<String[]> rowsAsTokensIt = rowsAsTokens.iterator();

    while (rowsAsTokensIt.hasNext()) {
        for (String token : rowsAsTokensIt.next()) {
            System.out.print(token + " ");
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To access items individually use the `[]` operator.

```
while (rowsAsTokensIt.hasNext()) {
    String[] tokens = rowsAsTokensIt.next();
    yourMethod(tokens[0], tokens[1], ..., tokens[15]);
}
```

or even shorter

```
for (String[] tokens: rowsAsTokens) {
    yourMethod(tokens[0], tokens[1], ..., tokens[15]);
}
```

alas Java has no splat operator so you have to spell out all 15 tokens. In a language with splat operator you'd just write `yourMethod(*tokens)` and it would work its magic for you.